# Three.js orthographic camera overlapping objects shining through

Tags: three.js, orthographic

In my scene I'm using an orthographic camera and a WebGLRenderer (`new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true })`). Two spheres are created by this code:

`new THREE.Mesh(
 new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 64, 64), 
 new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0xffffff })
)`

I shifted them away from each other with another code snippet, and for some reason they shine through each other, as marked in the picture even though they have the same size and the same location except from one axis.

[image: scene]

Does anyone know why this is the case and how I can fix it?

Comment: Can you show a live example -- or at least the complete code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! You can find a live example here: http://simsso.de/lcg.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your orthogarphic camera parameters are in the wrong order. Do this:

```
camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( -5, 5, 5, -5, 1, 11 );
camea.position.set( 0, 0, 6 );
```

Also, your `near` parameter should be positive, as it is a distance in front of the camera.

The camera is looking down the negative z-axis. In your case, do not rotate it.

three.js r.68